# How can I get security token from uaa server using Python or Postman

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa

How can I get security token from uaa server with user name and password. Can you give me working examples that I can use from Python and/or Postman to do three following things:
1. Log in.
2. Get the token.
3. Validate the token.
the endpoints from these uaa API docs do not work:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#verify-user-get-users-id-verify

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
import requests, json, jwt
client_auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('app', 'appclientsecret')
url = 'http://localhost:8080/uaa/oauth/token'
retval = requests.post(url=url, headers={'accept':'application/json'}, params=   {'username':'marissa','password':'koala', 'grant_type':'password','client_id':'app'}, auth=client_auth)
decode_token(json.loads(retval.content.decode('utf-8'))['access_token'])

def decode_token(token):
    print(token)
    docoded = jwt.decode(token, verify=False)
    print(decoded)
```

Postman:

```
POST /uaa/oauth/token? username=marissa&password=koala&client_id=app&grant_type=password HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic YXBwOmFwcGNsaWVudHNlY3JldA==
Cache-Control: no-cache
```